# jquery function stops working at the top of the page

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that acts on a click event of a list item:

```
<ul id="HowDoICategory"  class=" notranslate">
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item1">
     Register with the surgery
    </li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item2">
     Order a prescription</li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item3">
     Book an appointment</li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item4">
     Request a home visit</li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item5">
     Change my contact details</li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item6">
     Speak to a doctor/nurse</li>
    <li class="HowDoIItem" id="item7">
     Get my test results</li> 
</ul> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$("li.HowDoIItem").click(function(){
  //do something
});
</script>
```

When the script is at the bottom of the page this works.  However I want to move this into a separate file and reference at the top the page but this makes the click event stop working.

I've tried to put the javascript in a document ready function so it becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("li.HowDoIItem").click(function(){
    //do something
  });
});
</script>
```

but this doesn't work either.

Can someone explain what is happening here?
Thanks.

Comment: whoops!  the html has been stripped from the post.  I have an unordered list with each item looking like this: li class="HowDoIItem"

Comment: Can you post the HTML referencing the external JavaScript file? ie the `<head>` tag

Comment: to format code/html, select the code and click the `101010` button to indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only guess would be that you moved it too far up top, and you're referencing `$` for your `document.ready` handler *before* jQuery is included in the page.  Make sure to always have your code that relies on jQuery (external file or not) included *after* jQuery in the page.

Comment: Yes that was it.  Knowing a bit more about jquery now and finding that you must always wrap any function calls in $(function() { });  when the dom is ready.  Thanks.